# Is there a systematic way to determine where GC-pause causing objects are being instantiated with chrome developer tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, garbage-collection

It's clear from looking at the memory timeline that the severe pauses I am witnessing in my javascript execution are a result of garbage collection. What isn't clear is which objects are causing this problem. Is there a systematic way to find out? Something like a list of objects being garbage collected?

Comment: Another related question regarding gc in chrome http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547748/how-can-i-determine-what-objects-are-being-collected-by-the-garbage-collector