# JS: Profile What Objects Constructors are Garbage Collected

Tags: javascript, html, garbage-collection, profiling

Is there a way to know what type of objects are being garbage-collected the most in a Javascript application?

I do know I can get Heap Snapshot but that only tells what objects are the most common, not the most garbage-collected.

And Heap Allocations do not give detailed information about Object class.

Comment: that largely depends on the environment in which your JS is running. E.g. if you're executing on nashorn you can just use a JVM profiler.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Jodes See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429647/how-to-detect-the-memory-allocations-that-are-triggering-garbage-collection-in-j/

Comment: _"Is there a way to know what type of objects are being garbage-collected the most in a Javascript application?"_ How can Answer be provided without example `javascript` used?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do this by taking multiple heap snapshots and then comparing the snapshots to identify which objects are being grabage collected.
You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547748/how-can-i-determine-what-objects-are-being-collected-by-the-garbage-collector#answer-18364344) answer. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Using which JavaScript runtime engine?  Each engine will have its own GC and its own way of monitoring GC events.  The Chrome V8 engine would be a good place to start if you are trying to learn more about one GC implementation: https://developers.google.com/v8/  If you pull in the source from github https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git you will find files src/heap/gc-tracer.[h|cc] provide a lot of capability, and you could add more for your own profiling needs.

Comment: Daniel, this does not answer the question. The implementation of the GC engine is not the question. What is needed is a way of finding out which javascript objects the GC is collecting.

Comment: Look at the source code.  If he uses Chrome V8, he can get that info.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. How would one go about using the V8 code to speed up javascript? By modifying it and building a custom C++ javascript interpreter to get debug info?

Comment: The OP was how do you profile JS to find out what objects are garbage collected.  If you run your JS in Chrome V8 you can profile your JS code to find out what objects are garbage collected.  What you do with that information is up to you.