# How to detect the memory allocations that are triggering garbage collection in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, garbage-collection, google-chrome-devtools

While looking for performance issues in a JavaScript library (rivets), i found that garbage collection occurs three to four times in a run, taking ~15% of execution time (using Chrome DevTools JS Profile).

There are at least 30 places where temporary functions / objects are created being potential candidates for the reason of the garbage collection.

I'd like to know if there's a way to find what functions are responsible for the allocation of the memory being garbage collected, so i can focus my performance tuning.

I recorded Heap Allocation TimeLine but it does not differentiate memory that was garbage collected and that still holds a reference (there's no gray bar as pointed in DevTools [doc](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/memory-problems/allocation-profiler?hl=en))

Also recorded Heap Allocation Profile without luck.

Answer (score 1):

At `Profiles` tab at `DevTools` select `Record Heap Allocation`. Wrap `javascript` which should be evaluated within a call to `setTimeout()` with a duration set to enough time to click `Start` before function passed to `setTimeout` is called; for example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    t = 5;
    setTimeout(function() {
      (function test1() {
        var a = 123;
        function abc() {
          return a
        }
        abc();
      }());
    }, 10000)
  </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

When `setTimeout` is called a blue bar, possibly followed by a gray bar should appear at timeline. Click `Ctr+E` to stop recording heap profile.

Select blue or gray bar at timeline graph. Select `Containment` at dropdown menu where default option is `Summary`. Select

```
[1] :: (GC roots) @n
```

where `n` is a number.

Expand the selection by clicking triangle to left of `[1] :: (GC roots)`. Select an element of `[1] :: (GC roots)`, review the displayed `Distance`, `Shallow Size`, and `Retained Size` columns for the selection.

To check specific functions, scroll to

```
[2] :: (External strings) @n
```

to where global variables and function calls should be listed; i.e.g., `"t"` and `"setTimeout"` from above `javascrip`. Check corresponding `Distance`, `Shallow Size`, and `Retained Size` columns for the selection.

Comment: Many thanks. Following your instructions, i managed to identify specific functions. But the values show in shallow and retained seems to be the size of the function itself not the memory allocated at runtime. 
For example: function buildBinding (a method of a class) has a shallow size of 144 and retained size of 144, same as other functions.
But this function allocates some temporary objects like in 
` var context = pipes.shift().split("<").map(trimStr);
` 
I still could not find, for example, how much i would save in memory if i change the implementation to avoid these temporary objects.

Comment: @blikblum Is `var context = pipes.shift().split("<").map(trimStr);` listed on an individual line at output table?

Comment: No. It's part of the buildBinding body. Here is the actual code: https://github.com/blikblum/rivets/blob/svelte/dist/rivets.js#L337

Comment: @blikblum Interesting. Curious why the `var` is not listed at table? Will not provide garbage collection data, though you can use `console.time()`, `console.timeEnd()`, `console.profile()`, `console.profileEnd()` and `console.trace()` to check total time of the line to run.