# Does this graph suggest that there is a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks

I'm trying to isolate a memory leak in my app since the app becomes super slow after a while and eventually crashes, I've been using the Chrome dev tools in order to isolate where the problem could be, but so far I've come up short.

I just ran a timeline test and I think I've found something, but I'm not sure if I'm interpreting the results correctly.

This is the results:

[image: timeline]

The thing I found is that around 50 seconds, the number of event listeners (orange) and the javascript heap (blue) drops significantly, while the number of nodes (green) remains the same. It's as if the nodes are never removed while the listeners are.

Is this a correct interpretation of what's happening? Also what could be the cause of this, because as far as I know, I remove everything in directives for example using

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  $scope.$destroy();
  element.remove();
});
```

And while I cache the templates using `$templateCache` I don't see how that would cause memory leaks.

Overall it does appear that event listeners are removed correctly since it's on a fairly similar level throughout the test. So I'm starting to scratch my head over what's really at fault for the memory leaks here, if it's not the nodes causing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/39429647/

Comment: I'd say, that you need to run this operation several times during the course of a test to see, if the green nodes will increase w/o bounds. Since JS does eventual garbage collection (afaik), it might be an optimization trick to keep something in the pools. A single run might not be very conclusive.

Comment: @VladimirM I've run the test over and over and I get the same results, the green line just keeps going up and is never cleared. Is it an angular thing maybe?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I would highly recommend to go through [this article](http://www.dwmkerr.com/fixing-memory-leaks-in-angularjs-applications/), Author has explained how he has dealt with such issue.

Comment: @PankajParkar I did, but the issue still remains even with the most basic of apps. Look at this new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39587674/why-isnt-nodes-and-listeners-being-cleaned-up-properly-and-in-a-consistent-way