# Where can I find the real memory use of a page (including images and multimedia)?

Tags: javascript, memory, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I noticed something odd in the Memory inspector of both Chrome and Firefox. On a large page, it will tell you how much various JavaScript objects take up, but doesn't seem to list any image/multimedia objects. In fact, in this screenshot taking from the *Profiles* panel in Chrome's DevTools you can see most of the memory isn't in what it reported.

[image: Memory pie chart in Chrome]
(You can see this even on this page, going to Profiles -> Take Heap Snapshot, selecting Statistics from the top dropdown.)

Is there a more proper way to see how much memory is used by objects? Especially in Firefox - I ask because I had recently noticed a JavaScript profile and garbage collection took a very long time during page load.

Comment: You should probably link to an example or embed one in your question to make it easier for people to reproduce this.

Answer (score 3):

In Firefox press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to open the Developer Tools. Select the *Memory* tab. Check or select the available options, for example, *Record allocation stacks*, *View: Dominators*, *Label by: Type*. Click *Take snapshot* and scroll to review the *Retained Size (Bytes)*, the *Shallow Size (Bytes)* and the *Label* of objects.

See also [How to detect the memory allocations that are triggering garbage collection in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429647/how-to-detect-the-memory-allocations-that-are-triggering-garbage-collection-in-j) , [Clean-up of elements that are no longer referenced, and were never added to the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006399/clean-up-of-elements-that-are-no-longer-referenced-and-were-never-added-to-the/)

Comment: Note that the Memory tool is not available by default in Firefox 49 and earlier versions. To activate it switch to the DevTools settings and check the *Memory* option under *Default Developer Tools*. Starting in Firefox 50 it is enabled by default.

Comment: @SebastianZartner firefox 47 has `Memory` tab available.

Comment: If you look through it it seems it doesn't list large images on the page, just how much in the JS context.

Comment: @NoBugs You can check the `Network` tab at `Developer Tools`, select `Images`, reload `window` then review `Size` column of results.

Comment: @guest271314 That would be the size over the network (and Chrome doesn't even always show *that*). Memory decoded and stretched to certain dimensions rendered in the browser, will be a different value.

Comment: @NoBugs What do you mean by _"Chrome doesn't even always show that"_ Can you reproduce this? _"Memory decoded and stretched to certain dimensions rendered in the browser, will be a different value"_ What do you mean? Are you trying to determine the memory used by a user action to apply changes to an image after the image has been loaded within `document`?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, Chrome shows (from cache), unlike Firefox which shows the size. There used to be limits on dimensions in iOS for image size, and almost always in-memory image use will be differnet than the compressed jpeg or png or whatever format the pixels were compressed into and sent over the network.

Comment: No experience with ios. Though you should be able to determine the bytes of an image by requesting or creating a `Blob` of the image, then checking `.size` property of the resulting `Blob`.

Comment: @guest271314 I just use that as an example as there are many articles around about a *megapixel* limit iOS used to have. Here's just one: https://www.sitepoint.com/premium/books/build-mobile-websites-and-apps-for-smart-devices/preview/know-your-resource-limits-94747d7

Comment: @NoBugs As mentioned at previous comment, no experience with ios. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @guest271314 Trying to make it faster, use less memory... work great even on older desktops, etc.

Comment: @NoBugs _"Trying to make it faster, use less memory... work great even on older desktops, etc."_ What are you referencing by "it"?

Comment: @guest271314 A web page, images and all things referenced in it.

Comment: @NoBugs What is the benchmark? How is "faster" determined? Are images necessary? Can you include `html`, `css`, `javascript` at Question? What is issue with your present approach? Have you considered including description and details of what you are trying to achieve at Question?

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox there are two ways to measure the memory used by a page. One is described in guest271314's answer, which shows the memory usage in tree structures or as a visualized tree map. The other one is `about:memory`:

1. Go to [`about:memory`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/about:memory).
2. Click the *Measure* button.
3. In the displayed tree structure find the entry related to your page under `window-objects`, which looks like `top(<URL of your website>, id=<some ID>)` (depending on the size of your page it may be listed under a sub entry `(<number of small websites> tiny)`.

The number in MB besides the entry is the size of the page in memory.