# Can memory usage be reduced by avoiding var?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory-management

Let's say I have a class `MyClass` with a function `method()` that is going to be called **a lot**. Which of these implementations is going to be more efficient?

```
function MyClass() {
    this.method = function () {
        var number = 10;
        var boolean = true;
        var string = "string";

        // do something
    };
}

function MyClass() {
    this.data = {};
    this.method = function () {
        this.data.number = 10;
        this.data.boolean = true;
        this.data.string = "string";

        // do something
    };
}
```

The first implementation creates new variables which will be eligible for garbage collection after the execution of the function since there's no reference to them, which is great. However, if I call the function 3 times, there is memory allocated for a total of 3 numbers, 3 booleans and 3 strings.

The second implementation doesn't create new variables, it simply overwrites the values of the previous call of the function instead. Does this mean that after 3 invocations of the function, the memory allocated is just for 1 number, boolean and string, instead of 3? Is there really 3 times less memory consumed?

Comment: If you're willing to expose the data by using `this.data={}`, why wouldn't you just put the method on the `MyClass.prototype`? That would seem to be the most obvious enhancement you could make. As to your exact question, who knows. Depends on how the implementation is optimized.

Comment: ...in fact, even if you don't expose those members, is there some reason you're wanting to make a new function object every time? Making your code work properly comes first. After that, as with all performance questions, the answer is to test it.

Comment: ...also, `data` in the second example won't access `this.data`. So did you mean for `this.data = {}` to actually be a variable? Or did you mean to do `this.data.number = 10`?

Comment: I'm going to be calling the `method()` a lot, I'm not going to be creating multiple `MyClass` instances.


EDIT: I put `this` in the second example. I forgot it. Thanks!

Comment: You can get comparison of memory allocation for each approach by recording heap allocation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39728030/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-any-information-about-objects-being-released-using-ch/39728622#39728622 , recording allocation stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231122/where-can-i-find-the-real-memory-use-of-a-page-including-images-and-multimedia/40231716#40231716

Comment: @HristiyanDodov: Yes, I understand that'll be called a lot. I just wouldn't make any assumptions about performance based on what the code looks like. They do crazy optimizations, so the only way to truly know is to test it. I wouldn't believe any answer you get to this question, unless the person is very familiar with the optimizations in each implementation.

Comment: As I suggested, if you're willing to expose the data on `this`, then I wouldn't use either approach, but would rather put the function on the `.prototype` and have the data as properties on `this`, making sure they are either initialized on the `.prototype` or in the constructor. Some implementations are known to have extremely efficient optimizations for "classes" where all the properties of the class are known when the object is constructed. But even then, I'd do serious testing to be certain.

Comment: @HristiyanDodov There is no need to guess about memory usage or garbage collection. `DevTools` at chrome, chromium or `Developer Tools`  at firefox, nightly should provide results of memory allocation and garbage collection for both approaches. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/40006894/

Comment: I tried testing it, but I couldn't decide what's what. Recording allocation profile and timeline outputs nothing but blank space. I'm not sure exactly **how** to test something small like this...

Comment: I assume the method is run in a very tight loop. If so, you should be able to time that with `console.time` and `console.timeEnd`, but this can be tricky. Results can be deceptive. Unless you *consistently* get a *significant* difference, I wouldn't trust it.

Comment: I have a `setInterval` firing each millisecond with a `for` loop of 10,000,000 iterations that call `method()`. That's how I test both of the classes. Tricky part is - `console.time` and `timeEnd` my give me how fast the execution is, but I want to measure **memory**, not **time**. That's why I have an interval too - to eventually see progressive memory consumption. Bad thing is, allocation profile and timeline recordings give nothing. I guess because I don't use the `new` keyword anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
function MyClass() {
    this.method = function () {
        var number = 10;
        var boolean = true;
        var string = "string";

        // do something
    };
}
```

First approach is better as the variables are method scope and will be collected by GC once method execution is complete. But keep in mind if you have to keep these values as class members then this method will not work.

In second approach you are attaching these properties with class reference. So GC will not collect it until the class instance is referenced with some scope.

Comment: Why is that better? If the method is going to be called over and over, why is it better to create that data over and over instead of re-using the object? And which implementation favors one over the other in terms of performance?

Comment: I know GC won't collect the values. My main goal is to minimize memory usage. And in the first example, I'm allocating memory over and over, while in the second - I'm reusing it. I want to know if I **really** reuse memory and if yes, does it actually make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach looks very logical and accessible. I believe code is poetic and it tells a lot about persistence.

```
function MyClass() {
    this.data = {};
    this.method = function () {
        this.data.number = 10;
        this.data.boolean = true;
        this.data.string = "string";

        // do something
    };
}
```

the above code looks efficient and well structured than creating more var every single time your class is called.

Comment: What does "efficient" look like?

Comment: What do you think efficient should look like?

Comment: Why are you asking me? You're the one who claims that the code "looks efficient"

Comment: Lol. To me it looks efficient. I wont love to keep creating var. I would rather use this.
that's my opinion. Whats yours?

Comment: My opinion is that forming opinions of the efficiency of code based merely on how it looks is naive.

Comment: Well taken. I see and share my opinions based on a different light. Naive or not, I am happy I contributed on how beautiful I see the code to be... 

if it is not efficient, please be productive and share... We are all here to learn, and most times we learn by sharing. Do yourself a favor and learn how to carry a conversation appropriately without tension. If you think my answer is wrong, then you try to put me right and do it with wisdom.  
Carry on :)